# Stop javascript for some time

Tags: javascript, performance, load

I have the following code :

```
function require(url, callback, errcallback) {
    url = makeurl(url);

    var node = document.createElement('script');
    node.type = 'text/javascript';
    node.async = true;


    if (node.readyState) { //IE
        node.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (node.readyState == "loaded" || node.readyState == "complete") {
                node.onreadystatechange = null;
                callback;
            }
        };
    } else {
        node.onload = function () {
            callback;
        };
    }

    node.addEventListener('load', callback, false);
    node.addEventListener('error', errcallback);
    node.onerror = errcallback;
    node.src = url;

    head.appendChild(node);

    return require.getcontents(url);
};
```

The problem is when i'm loading some js file this is not fast enough and it will return a undefined error, when trying to call a function inside the file i'm trying to load.

example:

```
<script>
 require(['lib/static/jscript/smodule.js'], null , null );
</script>

<script>
  Smodule.somefunction();
</script>
```

It will say that Smodule is not defined.
(the file is loading but is not fast enough)

Comment: Anything that depends on the result of an asynchronous action should be done in its callback. So either put `Smodule.somefunction()` into the callback, or use `node.async = false`.

Comment: `callback;` should be `callback();`

Comment: node.async = false still not working and callback is already a function :
  require(['lib/static/jscript/smodule.js'], function(){alert('comething');} , null );

Comment: Why are you passing an array as the `url` argument to `require`? The function expects it to be a single URL.

Answer (score 2):

Put the call into the callback:

```
require(['lib/static/jscript/smodule.js'], function() {
    Smodule.somefunction();
}, null );
```

You're also not calling the callback properly in `require`, you need `()` after `callback` to call it:

```
if (node.readyState) { //IE
    node.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (node.readyState == "loaded" || node.readyState == "complete") {
            node.onreadystatechange = null;
            callback();
        }
    };
} else {
    node.onload = function () {
        callback();
    };
}
```

Comment: i can't do that because the server sends the rest of script one by one  ( php flush).

Comment: I don't think that should be a problem -- the `load` event shouldn't be triggered until it's completely received.

Comment: yes , but in this case i will not use the callback.
 the server first will send this:
  <script>
 require(['lib/static/jscript/smodule.js'], null , null );
</script>

and after this:
<script>
  Smodule.somefunction();
</script>


and it can't be separeted because using Bigpipe system